# Sutime / english.sutime.txt takes much loading time from runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, stanford-nlp

I am working on java project and i am using standford corenlp http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ library within it.

I have added them as reference library and also added some maven dependency. I have setup whole project with eclipse.

Now I create runnable jar for this project, but when I execute that jar it takes lot of time to execute library english.sutime.txt as follow,

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.4 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.9 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.0 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.6 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Jun 29, 2016 6:37:39 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt


Jun 29, 2016 6:58:03 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... 
done [3.1 sec].
```

So after english.sutime.txt I have to wait for further process about 15minutes. But project execute in eclipse not take this much time.

Can anyone help me to resolve this? My runnable jar contains all dependency within it.

Thanks,
Priyank

Answer (score 0):

While creating the runnable jar file in eclipse, select "Extract Required libraries into generated jar" instead of "Package required libraries into generated jar".